# How to keep Text within GTK CellRenderers at center?

Tags: application-development, gtk3

Hello I am using GTK3 CellRenderers in my project, but I want to put  **text within that at Center**, how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using a GtkCellrendererText here. If so, you just got to set the alignment property to center.
Example vala code:

```
my_cellrenderertext.alignment = Pango.Alignment.CENTER;
```

Comment: I tried, but it was not working....